How to remove the gray colored "spaces" in LibreOffice Writer?
When I open a document in LibreOffice Writer, between every word and any other place there is a "space" which it is in gray instead of the white background. It is very hard to read. Here is a sample. I can't figure out how to remove that formatting style.


You most likely have some non-breaking space characters in your text, possibly as a result of your file being a Microsoft Word one (.docx). There are several questions with the same issue online:

Weird Gray Spaces Between Words
Remove gray color of non-breaking spaces in Writer
Grey spaces in text when I open file created in word?

There are two easy solutions/workarounds for this.
Solution 1
Replace non-breaking spaces with spaces:

Use your mouse to select one of the gray squares.
Press Ctrl+H to bring up the Find and Replace menu.
Click in the Replace text field and press Space.
Click Replace All and Close.

Solution 2
Keep the non-breaking spaces but don't show them:

Go to View and uncheck Field Shadings.


PS: You probably also use an older version of LibreOffice (perhaps 7.X), because in more recent versions, in my case 24.8.2, non-breaking spaces aren't colored gray so you most likely wouldn't have this issue if you'd used a newer version.

I did think about 'find and replace' and then, when you mentioned it, OK, I actually tried it and it worked fine.  thanks

if that answered your question, perhaps consider accepting it so that others with the same issue can easily find the solution.

@PSimdars Just a ping for you to see Graham's comment above, because I am not sure that you received a notification.
